# Pipe not picking up stdout

Tags: io-redirection, pipe, stdout, output, stderr

I am running a java program from a `OS X 10.8` bash terminal, and are trying to rederect the output it is producing.

However, when either running this throug a pipe, or rederecting it to a file, the output is blank, however I see the output in the terminal.

To illustrate this:

```
> java program.java
13/10/02 14:18:30 WARN some
13/10/02 14:18:30 INFO log
13/10/02 14:18:30 INFO messages
...

> java program.java > log
> cat log
>
```

Can the java program be set up so that it is writing to another stream than `stdout`, but a stream that still produces output in the terminal. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting stderr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *three* standard files open for each program, `stdin` (standard input), `stdout`(standard output), and `stderr` (standard error). Writes to both `stdout` and `stderr` is output in the terminal by default.

It is a common convention to write errors and log messages to `stderr` instead of `stdout` in order to not mix log or error messages with actual program output. You can redirect `stderr` using `2>`, for instance:

```
command 2> log
```

Comment: Cool, worked. I tried `tail -f /dev/stderr` before, but that did not show anything, which led me to dismiss that it was writing to `stderr`. Shouldn't `/dev/stderr` have picked it up?

Comment: `/dev/stderr` is typically a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/2`. Your `tail` invocation tries to to read the `stderr` of the `tail` process itself, which of course yields no output.